# Are custom elements created by Angular components sectioning elements?

Tags: html, angularjs

When I use `angular.component()` or `angular.directive()` to create a custom element, is that treated as [sectioning content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#sectioning-content-0) or not?

That is to say, is it semantically and syntactically appropriate to generate a single `header` and `footer` internally, or does that count as being part of the containing element tree?

For example if I have

```
angular.component('foo', {
  template: `<header>Yay</header>`
})
```

And I use it so that the generated html is

```
<section>
   <foo>
      <header>Yay</header>
   </foo>
   <foo>
      <header>Yay</header>
   </foo>
</section>
```

Then what is the semantic? Is that a `section` which contains two `header` elements that are about the section? Or is it a `section` which contains zero header elements but two `foo` elements each with a header about the `foo`?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what your question is, and hard to answer without seeing your HTML structure.  *In general*, directives/components don't have any direct correlation with the HTML type;  The template can contain any valid HTML, Sections or not.  If you are using an Element Directive and asking if that specific Element (not it's contents) are Sectioning, that depends on what the name of the directive is;  i.e. you could make a directive `footer` and use it like `<footer></footer>`.....

Comment: @Claies I added an example and a better link if that helps clear it up

Comment: In that link, it says the sectioning content tags are "article, aside, nav, section", so it appears `foo` is not one of them. I would expect that it would be a `section` which contains two `header` elements. You can also see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#outlines, where it has an algorithm for how the (perhaps only in-memory) outline "should" be created.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I had assumed that custom elements had some sort of `isSectioning` flag in which case the question would be what does angular do with respec t to it

Comment: I don't believe AngularJS 1.x does anything with the [Custom Elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/) spec; it just leaves that element in the DOM. I've not used the component part of 1.5, but in directives you can mark `replace: true`, and the element will not remain in the DOM.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan yup, I believe the `replace: true` is deprecated in light of ng2

Comment: please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40431876/2545680), let me know if there is something unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular components/directives can generate any HTML tag, including those that are defined as `sectioning`, for example `angular.directive('article'...)`, or as `phrasing`, for example  `angular.directive('a'...)`, or custom elements, like `foo` in your example.

So it seems that your question is not so much about angular, but rather about custom elements and specifically what category they fall under. From reading the spec you linked, it depends on what your custom element is doing. If it's used for sectioning, and it has a header as in your example, I think it can be viewed as `sectioning content`. If your custom element is used for getting input from user, for example a `div` with `contenteditable=true`, then it can be treated as `interactive content`.

> Then what is the semantic? Is that a section which contains two header
>   elements that are about the section?

It depends on what you intended it to be. But since it has `header` child element, I would view `foo` as `sectioning content` and would say that it's a `section` element without a header that contains two other sections with headers.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it would be correct to add the header footer unless it was wrapped by a sectioning element in the template or the custom element itself declared the correct ARIA role. My first thought was to see the rules in web components in which I think it would be valid if you were to extend a sectioning element

Comment: I'm not sure I understand...so what does angular do? is there a way to change it up?